# Negative Value in Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

How can $ -2 \mod 26 = 24$? I can not understand it properly.

In my view point:

-2 mod 26 = .7.What is totally wrong. the real out put is 24, but how can anybody explain it clearly?

Comment: Can you explain your thoughts? In particular, how do you decide the answer should be .7 in your view? (By the way, the more traditional way to write this sort of thing is $-2\equiv 24 \pmod{26}.$)

Comment: I actually don't know how to mod negative value

Comment: There is no such thing as "$-2$ mod $26$". What is the the case is that $-2\equiv24\pmod{26}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation#Basic_example

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Not true, the binary operator form of mod is widely used both CS and math (including number theorists).

Comment: I am also curious as to how you got .7 as your first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an analog clock, there are $12$ numbers on it. If there are $2$ more hours before you reach $12$, what is the time now? $$12-2=10.$$

Now let's travel to another planet, there are $26$ numbers on it. There are $2$ more hours before you reach $26$, what is the time now? $$26-2=24.$$

Rather than going clockwise, go anti-clockwise for negative number.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition.**  Let $n$ be a positive integer.  Let $a, b$ be integers.  Then $a$ and $b$ are said to be *congruent modulo* $n$, denoted $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$, if and only if $a - b = kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Since $-2 - 24 = -26 = (-1)26$, we obtain $-2 \equiv 24 \pmod{26}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $26 - 2 = 24$. The numbers of the form $26m - 2$ are $$\ldots, -106, -80, -54, -28, -2, 24, 50, 76, 102, \ldots$$

So $-2 \bmod 26$ means a number that is 2 to the "left" of a multiple of 26, or 24 to the "right" of a multiple of 26.

Happy Friday the 26th.